# Node child process doesn't release port, even after it's killed by parent

Tags: node.js

I have a parent node process and a child node process. The child binds a web server to port 5000. The parent sometimes kills and restarts the child (usually because a file has changed).

The problem is: when the second child process starts, I get `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5000`.

The weird thing is, I kill the child process with `child.kill()`, then I wait for it to fire a `close` event, and *then* I wait 5 seconds with `setTimeout`, before trying to start a new child process...yet it always complains that the port is occupied. But if I manually kill the parent process (ctrl+C in my terminal) and run it again, I don't get the error. So killing the parent seems to be the only way to successfully release the port.

Can anyone think of a reason why this would happen? Why does the port remain occupied after the process that bound it is killed, until its *parent* process stops?

Comment: Interesting, are you using something like [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) for running the parent ?

Comment: please, provide more info, code. How you start process

Answer (score 0):

Actually it block the process so you need to kill the process by following command just type

**ps -ax**

You will get list of processes from where you need to check the process id which is been blocked then kill the process by this command

**kill -9 processId**

Answer (score 0):

Kill all your running port by below command.

`pkill node`